# EF Core restore complex entity

Tags: json, restore, ef-core-2.1

I have a complex entity that holds several List members, each of which hold further sub-list entities.
We have the need to 'backup' and then restore the entire object, so we thought it would be easy enough to serialize the object to Json - and then the restore would be a simple deserialize back into the master object.
This produces the error,

> "The instance of entity type 'MasterObject' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked...."

Clearly it doesn't recognize my restored object as the original being tracked.
We've tried detaching the tracked objects and then re-attaching and that works to a point; it fails to help when a sub-list has had some items removed or added - the tracking won't help us to delete items after that moment.
We could figure out the exact changes and then individually mark as delete etc. but we're really doing what EF will be doing later anyway, and there's an awful lot of changes to test for.
We also tried

> "Context.Entry(myObject).CurrentValues.SetValues(objectFromBackup)"

but the same issue occurs for removed/added sub-items.
Is there a better approach to restoring complex entities that we can try?

Answer (score 0):

We fixed this by using sequences instead of identities on all the tables that need to be reverted, then deleted and re-added via EF core and that seems to work.
Any other suggestions still welcome.